# create-react-app CSS and JS path

Tags: reactjs

After running [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)'s `npm run build`, the created `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>React App</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link href="/main.e606e04b6e0092a87205a9dc4662479c.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/main.35180d284d8a2058f717.js"></script></body></html>
```

Both, `script` and `link` `src`/`href`-attributes, point to the wrong direction. The leading `/` should be removed, because all generated files are in the same directory. Is this a bug or can I configure these paths somehow?

Comment: It's not a bug. It makes sure it get those particular files on different routes aside the index's

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The generated files are supposed to be served from a web server. When you run `npm run build`, you should see the instructions on starting a simple local web server in that directory. If you deploy this directory to a real web server and serve `index.html` from the root, it will also work fine.

If the generated file referenced scripts without `/`, your site would break as soon as you add client side routing. For example, if an app is located at `mysite.com` but also handles a URL like `mysite.com/about`, relative paths would cause scripts to be loaded from `mysite.com/about/*.js` which would be a 404 error. This is why all paths start from root by default.

If you want to serve your app from a subdirectory (from example `myuser.github.io/myproject`), you will need to add `"homepage"` field in your `package.json`, for example:

```
  "homepage": "http://myuser.github.io/myproject"
```

Create React App will **infer the correct root path based on the `homepage` setting**. This feature is available since `react-scripts@0.2.0`

Please read the [deployment instructions](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/884d56738dd21f750b880a9bf3a8abff02023f3e/template/README.md#deploying) for more information.

Comment: I set `{"homepage": "."}`, and then rerun `phonegap run build`. The links are changed to `src="./main.123456.js"`. Now my app works on phonegap :-)

Comment: We don't officially support `{"homepage": "."}` even though it works in some cases. It breaks in other cases.

Comment: Looks life the `{"homepage": "."}` feature is supported with react-scripts@0.9.0 and higher. Source: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was having the same problem. Before I had `{"homepage": "./"}` and changing it to `{"homepage": "/"}` in `package.json` seems to solve my problem.